# Search list of keywords in elastic using R elastic package

Tags: r, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am making a shiny app where a user can input an excel file of terms and search them on elastic holdings. The excel file contains one column of keywords and is read into a list, then what I am trying to do is have the each item in the list searched using Search(). I easily did this in Python with a for loop over the terms and then the search connection inside the for loop and got accurate results. I understand that it isn't that easy in R, but I cannot get to the right solution. I am using the R elastic package and have been trying different versions of Search() for over a day. I have not used elastic before so my apologies for not understanding the syntax much. I know that I need to do something with aggs for a list of terms..

Essentially I want to search on the `source.body_` field and I want to use `match_phrase` for searching my terms.

Here is the code I have in Python that works, but I need everything in R for the shiny app and don't want to use reticulate.

```
queries = list()
    for term in my_terms:
        search_result = es.search(index="cars", body={"query": {"match_phrase": {'body_':term}}}, size = 5000)
        search_result.update([('term', term)])
        queries.append(search_result)
```

I established my elastic connection as `con` and made sure it can bring back accurate matches on just one keyword with:

```
match <- {"query": {"match_phrase" : {"body_" : "mustang"}}}

search_results <- Search(con, index="cars", body = match, asdf = TRUE)
```

That worked how I expected it to with just one keyword explicitly defined.

So after that, here is what I have tried for a list of `my_terms`:

```
aggs <- '{"aggs":{"stats":{"terms":{"field":"my_terms"}}}}'

queries <- data.frame()

for (term in my_terms) {

final <- Search(con, index="cars", body = aggs, asdf = TRUE, size = 5000)
rbind(queries, final)
}
```

When I run this, it just brings back everything in my elastic. I also tried running that with the for loop commented out and that didn't work.

I also have tried to embed `my_terms` inside my match list from the single term search at the beginning of this post like so:

```
match <- '{"query": {"match_phrase" : {"body_": "my_terms"}}}'

Search(con, index="cars", body = match, asdf = TRUE, size = 5000)
```

This returns nothing. I have tried so many combinations of the `aggs` list and `match` list but nothing returns what I'm looking for. Any advice would be much appreciated, I feel like I've read just about everything so far and now I'm just confused.

UPDATE:
I figured it out with

```
p <- data.frame()
for (t in the_terms$keyword) {
  result <- Search(con, index="cars", body = paste0('{"query": {"match_phrase" : {"body_":', '"', t, '"', '}}}'), asdf = TRUE, size = 5000)
  p <- rbind(p, result$hit$hit)
}
```

Comment: `elastic` maintainer here. there's a lot of factors here. i'd suggest doing `connect(errors = "complete")` so that more verbose elasticsearch errors are reported in R when they happen. id update your question w/ Elasticsearch version and `elastic`  version being used.

Comment: @sckott I am using Elasticsearch version number: "6.8.3"  and the version of elastic is ‘1.0.0’.

Comment: @sckott I also have just tried this: `for (term in the_terms) {
  p <- Search(con, index="cars", body = as.list(paste0("'", '{"query": {"match_phrase" : {"body_":', '"', term, '"', '}}}', "'")), asdf = TRUE, size = 5000)

  }` So now I can at least access my terms that are in the list and create the query structure correctly. However, when I do this I get the error `Error: 400 - Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [START_ARRAY]`

Comment: looks like you figured it out, in the future you can open issues at https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues for any elastic problems

Comment: hi @sckott, I am having another issue with the elastic pkg, but i didn't want to post on the github unless i knew if it was an actual problem and not just me....was wondering if you could take a look? the post is here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698273/data-frame-created-from-search-elastic-in-r-but-receiving-error-conn-must-be) thank you in advance! i'm at a loss for this one