# Data frame created from Search() elastic in r, but receiving error 'conn must be an elastic connection object when using resulting dataframe

Tags: r, elasticsearch, rstudio

I'm using the elastic package in R, Elasticsearch version number "6.8.3" and the version of elastic pkg is ‘1.0.0’. I have a a function to search elastic based on an input list of keywords, and the output is a dataframe of hits$hits. This dataframe is then used in another function which does data manipulation and makes a plot.

However, when I use the resulting dataframe in the data manipulation function, I keep getting this error when running a certain piece of the data manipulation function, which doesn't even mention elastic in it: `Error: 'conn' must be an elastic connection object; see ?connect`

Here is the elastic function:

```
keyword_search <- function(file) {
  library(elastic)
  library(readxl)
  library(rjson)
  library(magrittr)

  con <- connect(host = '10.0.53.250', port = 9200)

#file is an excel file with "keyword" in the first cell of the first column, #then one search term per cell going down the column
  the_terms <- read_excel(file)
  the_terms %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    as.list()
  r <- data.frame()

  for (t in the_terms$keyword) {
    print(t)
    result <- Search(con, index="cars", body = paste0('{"query": {"match_phrase" : {"body_":', '"', t, '"', '}}}'), asdf = TRUE, size = 5000)
    r <- rbind(r, result$hits$hits)
  }
icars <- r
return(icars)
}
```

The data manipulation function:

```
wordcloud_table  <- function(icars) {

  library(wordcloud2)
  library(dplyr)
  library(readxl)
  library(tidytext)
  library(wordcloud)
  library(tidyr)
  data(stop_words)
  source('stemmer.R')

  custom_stopwords <- c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0',  'hey', 'hehe')

  custom_stopwords_df <- tibble(word = custom_stopwords)

  clean_cars_df <- icars %>% 
    dplyr::select(report_name, body_)

  tidy_cars<- clean_cars_df %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, body_)

  stopwords_df<- tibble(word = stopwords())

  tidy_cars <- tidy_cars %>%
    anti_join(stopwords_df)

  tidy_cars <- tidy_cars %>%
    anti_join(stop_words)

  tidy_cars <- tidy_cars %>%
    anti_join(custom_stopwords_df)

  wordcountdata <- tidy_cars %>% count(word)

  forwordcloud <- as.data.frame(wordcountdata)
  return(forwordcloud)
}
```

Then I run

```
icars <- keyword_search("keywords_onecol.xlsx")

wordcloud_table(icars)
```

Every time I get the 'conn connection object error right when the code gets to `wordcountdata <- tidy_cars %>% count(word)` in the wordcloud function, and I cannot understand why, because there in no conn in that function, and that's also very random for it to get hung up on that part of the code and not the very first use of tidy_cars. Hopefully somebody can help me figure this out, I am at a loss...

Here is the traceback:

```
12.
stop("'conn' must be an elastic connection object; see ?connect", 
    call. = FALSE) 
11.
is_conn(conn) 
10.
count(., word) 
9.
function_list[[k]](value) 
8.
withVisible(function_list[[k]](value)) 
7.
freduce(value, `_function_list`) 
6.
`_fseq`(`_lhs`) 
5.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
4.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env) 
3.
withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)) 
2.
tidy_cars %>% count(word) 
1.
wordcloud_table(icars)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have conflicting function names: `elastic::count` and `dplyr::count`. if both packages are loaded, then one package overrides the other's fxn of the same name. You can fix most easily by namespacing the function all, so just change `count()` to `dplyr::count` (i assume you were trying to use dplyr's count)

Comment: that was exactly it...thank you so much. works perfectly now! silly me for not realizing that